# Guiding the solution of ODE with curves

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

> Let $f:\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $\frac{df}{dx}$ is well-defined and continuous on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. Assume $\gamma \in C^1([0,+\infty[)$ is increasing with $\gamma(0) > 0$ and such that $\forall t \ge 0. f(t,\gamma(t)) \le 0 \le f(t,0)$.
>
> Now consider the problem $\begin{cases}x' = f(t,x) \\ x(0) = 0\end{cases}$ and note $x_0:[0,\omega_0[ \to \mathbb{R}$ its maximal solution.
>
> Show that $\omega_0 = +\infty$ and $\forall t \ge 0. 0 \le x_0(t) \le \gamma(t)$.

How would you prove such a statement, my main tool here (first instant lemma I don't know a standard name for it) does not work here since $x$ is starting at $0$. What guarantee I have that the solution will not fall below $0$?

**A diagram describing the situation**

[image]

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2973575/divergence-of-the-solution/2973744) is related to yours: the ODE studied there is *linear*, but the hypothesis you state on $\frac{d f}{dx}$ can be used to give the same conclusions

Comment: @DanieleTampieri I don't really see how to use $\frac{df}{dx}$...I thought it was only for uniqueness of the solution

Comment: I had a quick flash, so it is nothing more than an impression, but I think the following expansion $$ x'(t)=f(t,x)\simeq f(t,x_0)+\partial_x f(t,x_0)\cdot x(t)$$ could be manipulated in order to obtain something similar to the equation studied in that question, since you can always assume that locally, on every interval $[a,b]\in\Bbb R$, $0\le |\partial_x f(t,x_0)\cdot x(t)| \le M_{[a,b]}$, i.e. you can assume the local boundedness of the second side of the given ODE.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri thank you for your observation. Could I use that to show that $x(t)$ is over zero?

Comment: In the same way as you find a maximal solution, I  think you could find a *minimal solution* and see if you can control the behavior of the solution by the maximal and minima ones, provided the latest has the sought for properties. Again, this is more a suggestion based on intuition than an answer.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri : Usually the "maximal" in "maximal solution" refers to the domain on which the solution is defined on. The existence theorems generally only guarantee "minimal" or local solutions.

Comment: @LutzL thank you for pointing out the inaccuracy in the terminology. For *minimal solution* I meant a solution of an ODE whose right side vector field is always "less or equal" to the original one: I didn't mean a local solution to the given ODE.